# Won't this jk flip flop circuit be facing a race condition?

Tags: flipflop

Below is the question and answer for my assignment but I don't really understand why it shows the output as below:

[image]

[image]

I am confused here.

Shouldn't the circuit for flip-flop A which is connected to flip-flop B look as below with the output Q connect to the clock input of flip-flop B?

This is not a master-slave flip flop circuit. Wouldn't it be facing a race condition? Shouldn't I get a lot of square waves that consist of 1010 in every interval of \$f_{in}\$ when it is high for the graph QA rather than a square wave for a complete cycle of clock input?

[image]

Comment: Clearly it's an edge-triggered flip-flop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JK Flip Flop toggle action](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/148932/jk-flip-flop-toggle-action)

Comment: The action you describe seems to be that of an RS *latch*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circuits you added at the end of your question **do not** show two edge-triggered flip-flops. Those circuits show two **level-sensitive latches**.

The symbol in the top schematic shows a little triangle at the clock pin of each flip-flop. That triangle is the standard indication that the device is edge sensitive.

Comment: Thank you, I been circling around for some time.